# ¿Recuperar valores de mi tabla?

Tags: javascript, json, codeigniter

Quiero guardar en una variable los datos de mi tabla por ejemplo mi json me trae 2 campos, nombre y fecha.

Y quiero que el primer dato de nombre lo guarde en una variable:

**ejemplo:**
 var nom = 'el primer registro de nombre';
 var fech = 'el primer registro de fecha';

y asi de uno en uno ir recorriendo en un `foreach` para mandalos y realizar la consulta

De esta manera agrego los datos a mi tabla:

```
$('#ejemplo').bootstrapTable({
  url:'<?= base_url(); ?>index.php/ejemplo/nombres/datos',
  columns: [
    {field: 'nombre',filter:{type:"input"}},
    {field: 'fecha',filter:{type:"input"}}
  ]
});
```

Alguien que me ayude?

Answer (score 0):

A que te refieres con usar un `forEach` para mandarlos y realizar la consulta?

si quieres llenar la tabla con una URL solo debes asegurarte que tu URL devuelva una lista de objetos, cada objeto con los mismos atributos que tus nombres de tus fields en tus columnas, de esta manera:

```
    [{"nombre": "Nombre 1", "fecha": "25-05-2016"},
     {"nombre": "nombre 2", "fecha": "10-02-2005"}]
```

aqui te dejo un ejemplo que esta en la misma documentacion del bootstrap table: [ejemplo aqui!!!](http://jsfiddle.net/a0fh8hxp/)